# How to allocate specific number of mappers to multiple job in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am executing multiple PIG Scripts say script1, script2, script3, script4. In that I script1 is executing independently and script2,3,4 executing parallely after scripts get executed.
I am giving input file of size 7-8 GB. So after executing script1, I am observing that instead of parallely executing script 2,3,4 only script2 is executing as it is consuming 33-35 mappers. Other remain in like queue (means script3,4 have not get mapper allocation). Due to this too much time requires to execute all scripts.

So what I am thinking is that If I am able to set the limit of mapper to each script then may be time require to execute wll be less as all scripts may get allocation of mappers.

So is there any way to allocate specific number of mappers to multiple scripts?

Answer (score 0):

If your map number is correctly set (according to your core/node and disks/node values), then having 1 job consuming all your maps or having N job consuming MapNumber / N maps will have the same result. But if you really want to distribute your maps on an amount of jobs you can set the per job map number (`mapreduce.job.maps` in `mapred-site.xml` i think).

Considering you still have free map slots, there are some config to enable jobs parallel executions like discussed here : [Running jobs parallely in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483624/running-jobs-parallely-in-hadoop)

You can also set a map number for each job (even if I am not sure it really works) if you provide a job.xml in which you set your map number to your hadoop command.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following line at the beginning of your script :

set mapred.map.tasks 8

and this will let all of your scripts to run concurrently.

please note that if your machine is saturated this will not affect how long all the scripts run