# Submitting parallel jobs from the same client to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing

I have a three node Hadoop 2.6 cluster on which I tried to run multiple instances of TestDFSIO in parallel by using "&" at the end of each command. But it turns out that only one of those jobs gets submitted and processed by the cluster and the rest are not even submitted (somehow thrown away). So, was wondering if this has anything with Hadoop's Yarn or MapReduce options or anything else.

Comment: Found the last answer of the following link very relevant but could not find the corresponding options in Yarn or MapReduce configurations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483624/running-jobs-parallely-in-hadoop

Comment: We submit multiple jobs simultaneously no issues, There might be some thing else, Check the errors by redirecting the stdout and stderr to a file.